# Batch calls in webflux api when number of records is not known

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to call the api, in batches. Ex :- First batch will call with offset 0 - limit -10,000
and second one with offset- 10,000, limit-10,000(bring 10,000 -20,000) and third one with offset-20,000 and limit -10,000(bring 20,000 - 30,000). It will break once it has fetched all records, but I see more number of calls than expected.

Sample code :

```
AtomicBoolean makeNextCall = new AtomicBoolean(true);
Flux.fromStream(Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1))
                    .takeWhile(integer -> {
                        LOGGER.withTask(GET_TRANSACTIONS)
                                .withMessage(String.format("Batch =[%s] and MaxResultsReturned = [%s]", integer, makeNextCall.get()))
                                .info();
                        return makeNextCall.get();
                    }).concatMap(counter -> {
                        int histOffset = counter * batchSize;
                        return bbTransactionRepository.accountTransactions(transactionContext, histOffset, batchSize)
                                .flatMap(tranList -> {
                                    int size = ((List<BBTransaction>) tranList).size();
                                    LOGGER.withTask(GET_TRANSACTIONS)
                                            .withAttribute(RESULT, size)
                                            .withAttribute(HIST_OFFSET, histOffset)
                                            .withAttribute(HIST_LIMIT, batchSize)
                                            .withAttribute(BATCH, counter)
                                            .withMessage("fetching bb transactions in batches")
                                            .info();
                                    boolean shouldContinue = size >= batchSize;
                                    makeNextCall.set(shouldContinue);
                                    return Mono.just(tranList);
                                });
                    })
                    .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
                    .collectList()
```

So for 26,000 records, there should be 3 calls and then break since 3 call(6,000 < batch.size(10,000)
But I see around 33 calls in UAT env, it works correctly in local env though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the code but the best way to validate the flow is to create a test using `StepVerifier`.

As for batch processing I would suggest to simplify the code and use `Flux.buffer` to process data and `Flux.takeUntil` to cancel the publisher when condition matches.

```
private Flux<List<Integer>> processInBatch(int batchSize) {
    AtomicInteger offset = new AtomicInteger();

    return Flux.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .buffer(batchSize)
            .concatMap(batch -> {
                var histOffset = offset.getAndAdd(batch.size());

                log.info("offset: {}, batch: {}", histOffset, batch.size());
                return accountTransactions(histOffset, batch.size());
            })
            .doOnNext(res -> log.info("res: {}", res.size()))
            .takeUntil(res -> res.size() < batchSize);
}
```

and here is a test to verify the flow

```
@Test
void validateBuffer() {
   StepVerifier.create(processInBatch(26000, 10000))
       .expectNextCount(3)
       .verifyComplete();
}
```

```
23:00:11.341  [Test worker] INFO - offset: 0, batch: 10000
23:00:11.369  [Test worker] INFO - res: 10000
23:00:11.370  [Test worker] INFO - offset: 10000, batch: 10000
23:00:11.371  [Test worker] INFO - res: 10000
23:00:11.372  [Test worker] INFO - offset: 20000, batch: 10000
23:00:11.372  [Test worker] INFO - res: 6000
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, looks pretty clean. But I don't know the recordCount, i need to keep consuming until all data is processed.

Comment: Is it defined by result of the `accountTransactions` (size >= batchSize)?

Comment: yes it is defined by the result of accountTransactions (size >= batchSize)

Comment: could you provide more info regarding `accountTransactions ` . what is the return type and  how result size could be greater than batchSize?

Comment: Yup accountTransactions is result of the apiCall(v1/transactions/ACCOUNT3?hist_offset=0&hist_limit=10) which bbTransactionRepository.accountTransactions make. Consider a scenario where total record of the api is 21 and batch size is 10, so first call will be v1/transactions/ACCOUNT3?hist_offset=0&hist_limit=10, and result size 10 which is equal to batch size 10.

Comment: Second call will be v1/transactions/ACCOUNT3?hist_offset=10&hist_limit=10 and result size will be 10 equal to batch size. Third call will be v1/transactions/ACCOUNT3?hist_offset=20 &hist_limit=10 and result will be 1 which is less than batch size.

Comment: then you can use `takeUntil` to cancel the publisher when condition matches. Updated the answer